# How to include line breaks and bullet points when scraping with node.js?

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping

When scraping the description of [Glassdoor job page](https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/job-listing/long-term-internship-july-2021-merchant-banking-london-rothschild-JV_IC2671300_KO0,54_KE55,65.htm?jl=3796681291&pos=105&ao=1136006&s=58&guid=0000017a3283e1059b031339cea1fca8&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SR&vt=w&uido=A07C859157E656FE734518C723EC904C&cs=1_1e078673&cb=1624345141661&jobListingId=3796681291&ctt=1624345167344) the result of
`$("#JobDescriptionContainer").text()` returns the text string without line breaks, new paragraphs or bullet points. Is there any way to scrape the description so that the returned result is formatted in the same way as on the website instead of just pure unformatted text?

Comment: Try .innerHTML() or .html()

Comment: Thanks, it works. But when it is then saved in MongoDB it's one large string of text without breaks again. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Please use .html() instead of .text()

```
$("#JobDescriptionContainer").html()
```

Comment: Thanks, works! However, later when it is saved at MongoDB, it becomes one large string without breaks - do you know how to store it at mongoDB in correct format as well?